# Python stock correlation heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation, stock

Trying to make a correlation heatmap of stocks in a portfolio, however result is messed up. Help is appreciated.

Get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzuE.jpg

```py
pt_comp = web.DataReader(['BP.L', 'III.L', 'GSK.L', 'OCDO.L', 'RBS.L', 'SVT.L'], 'yahoo',start=start,end=end) ['Adj Close']

#Percentage returns of each stock 

pt_rets = pt_comp.pct_change()

#correlation between stocks 

corr = pt_rets.corr()

#corrlation heat map


plt.imshow(corr, cmap='hot', interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(len(corr)), corr.columns)
plt.yticks(range(len(corr)), corr.columns);

'''
```

Comment: What do you mean by "results is messed up"? I think adding what your expectations were and what you actually got would be helpful.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzuE.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to plot a correlation heatmap is to use seaborn library. See, if it helps.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pt_comp = web.DataReader(['BP.L', 'III.L', 'GSK.L', 'OCDO.L', 'RBS.L', 'SVT.L'], 'yahoo',start=start,end=end) ['Adj Close']

#Percentage returns of each stock 

pt_rets = pt_comp.pct_change()

#correlation between stocks 

corr = pt_rets.corr()

ax = sns.heatmap(corr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(len(corr)), corr.columns)
plt.yticks(range(len(corr)), corr.columns)
```

Comment: Perfect, is there a way to create a correlation scatter matrix with a diagonal kde in seaborn?